# Modify BOOL inside method in iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios, parameter-passing, pass-by-reference

I have a `UITableView`which displays cells with images. On the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method I launch a connection to fetch the image. I want to keep track of what images have been already requested in order to avoid requesting the same image multiple times.

I set up a method like this

```
+(void) setImageFromURL:(NSURL*) url fromImage:(UIImage*) srcImage to:(UIImageView*) dstImage wasRequested:(BOOL*) requested;
```

and call it like this

```
[Utils setImageFromURL:event.thumbURL fromImage:event.thumbImage to:cell.image wasRequested:event.thumbRequested];
```

where event.thumbRequested is a BOOL property. The method look like this

```
+(void) setImageFromURL:(NSURL*) url fromImage:(UIImage*) srcImage to:(UIImageView*) dstImage wasRequested:(BOOL*) requested{
    if (srcImage != nil) {
        dstImage.image = srcImage;
    } else if (!requested) {
        requested = YES;
        @try {
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
                NSData * data = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL: url];
                if ( data == nil )
                    return;
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                    __block UIImage* srcImage = [UIImage imageWithData: data];
                    dstImage.image = srcImage;
                });
                [data release];
            });
        }
        @catch (NSException *exception) {
            NSLog(exception.debugDescription);
        }
    }
}
```

My problem is the `BOOL` is not changing due to the pass by value behavior in `Objective-C`. Can anyone recommend a way for being able to update the `BOOL` in the event object from inside the mehod?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The line:

```
requested = YES;
```

needs to be:

```
if (requested) {
    *requested = YES;
}
```

The check is just incase `nil` was passed in for `requested`.

Edit: And the call should be:

```
BOOL requested = event.thumbRequested;
[Utils setImageFromURL:event.thumbURL fromImage:event.thumbImage to:cell.image wasRequested:&requested];
event.thumbRequested = requested;
```

Comment: I am facing another problem with this code, fromImage UIImage* parameter should be initialized in the method but the variable in event instance is not assigned. How can I solve that?

Comment: Awesome, thanks. I forgot "never dereference the null pointer".